# How to fix table going outside of div tag in IE6 & 7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, tablelayout

If a table is too big and the window is too small than the table goes outside the div.

I solved this with `display:table !important;` on the surrounding div but it doesn't work in IE 6&7 because they don't know it. How can I solve this in IE6 & 7?

See JSFiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kevin1990/LNS26/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `display: table`, use `float: left`.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/LNS26/16/

This makes use of the "shrink wrap"/"shrink to fit" effect you get on a floated element if you don't specify an explicit `width`.