# Container div width problem

Tags: css, width, doctype

Can anybody tell me why the outer div is not expanding to the page width? Is there any solution for this without removing the doctype declaration(If I remove doctype, it is expanding) ? Also my page is in js disabled mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1 /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="border:1px solid #ff0000;">

        <div>
            <table class="storeList">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Country Code
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Store ID
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Store Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            TownName
                        </th>
                        <th class="actions">
                            Store Operation
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            TEST
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TEST
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            hghjgdkjvhkjhvhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjhghjgdkjvhkjhvhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhgfdhf
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TEST
                        </td>
                        <td class="actions">
                            TEST ACTIONS
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer works, promise!

To your outermost `div` (`<div style="border:1px solid #ff0000;">`), add either:

- `float: left`, or;
- `display: inline-block`.

If you would like to see demos of these two fixes, check these older answers I provided:

- [How to fix table going outside of div tag in IE6 & 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538705/how-to-fix-table-going-outside-of-div-tag-in-ie6-7/5539203#5539203)
- [Expand a div width to the width of the sibling table which has a lot of rows and causes vertical scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819796/expand-a-div-width-to-the-width-of-the-sibling-table-which-has-a-lot-of-rows-and/5819869#5819869)

Comment: Hi, Can you check the below url? Here why the ul is not expanding upto the width of the container ? 
http://jsfiddle.net/aneesh/LNS26/21/

Comment: Stick a `clear: both` on the element after the element with `float: left`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/LNS26/24/ - if you want the red background on the `ul` to extend to the width of the table, move the `ul` inside the containing `div`.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be because browsers apply their own default style, which include margins and padding on various elements. The body tag probably has default padding so you'd need to add a "reset CSS" file to your page to reset these defaults or just try:

```
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

In the head of your page. Also, just to note, it looks like you're using tables for layout. This is a big no no in todays modern world of CSS:

http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/

http://www.mardiros.net/css-layout.html

[Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

Comment: No need to remove the margin/padding of every single element for this, just the body tag is enough, or maybe the html tag as well.

Comment: Also, it looks like he’s using a table to… lay out data as a table (a list of stores with several columns). Nothing wrong with that. In fact, it has been a big yes-yes since the beginning of times.

Comment: It is not working with the reset css. I can't omit the table since it is a tabular data :( Could you please copy and paste the code given and let me know whether it is working ?

Comment: @Olbaum - I added the Universal Selector example as you don't generally run into the problem just once when building a web page. And in response to the second question, you're right... but then I see redundant elements instead, almost the same thing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set your table to 100% width to cover the area provided by the div

```
table { width: 100%; }
```